visual studio code, How can i remove solid underline from functions
enter image description hereI have made a custom colour theme, I just cannot work out how to get rid of the solid green underline from functions.
Im hoping to remove the solid underline i cant find anything online who has had the same problem as what i want to fix

with the Dev Tools find what is causing this green line

find the TextMate Scope of the green underlined words, and customize that scope
